# Memory is not getting released after use In Puma Docker Container

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker, rubygems, amazon-ecs, puma

We are using Puma with cluster mode where we are using 3 workers with 5 threads. Once the container application is up it starts consuming memory by Puma workers at a high rate and after some time memory utilization by workers slows down but increases step by step.
After the memory is utilized 100% it stops the container and starts again.

This is really a big problem we are facing.

Attaching the Memory utilization Graph for Rails Puma Application.
[image]

Comment: Ruby doesn't release memory https://www.joyfulbikeshedding.com/blog/2019-03-14-what-causes-ruby-memory-bloat.html (this article provides a few tips) Just make sure you don't have a memory leak. Otherwise provide more Ram.

Comment: @Maxence we are facing this issue after we moved from Unicorn to puma with containerizing. Before that, it was running smoothly with Unicorn on the server.